# Lorentz transformation in extra-dimension

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, group-theory

The Lorentz transformation is usually defined In 4D spacetime, how can we derive the generalized transformation in extra-dimensional space-times like 5D or more dimensions?

Comment: What do you suppose to be the 5th or higher dimension in reality?

Comment: Hint: The [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Generalization_to_higher_dimensions) can be generalized to any spacetime dimension.

Comment: either a real dimension or just a mathematical tool

Comment: Consider, say SO(1,4), with coordinates $t,x,y,z,w$. For additional generators (compared with 4D) I think you’ll just have three extra rotations (in the $xw$, $yw$, and $zw$ planes) and one extra boost (in the $w$ direction, equivalent to a hyperbolic rotation in the  $tw$ plane). In other words… more of the transformations that you already know.

Comment: My guess is that the new feature of SO(1,4)  is that a generic Lorentz transformation is no longer the product of a single boost in some direction and a single rotation in some plane. Instead, the fact that there are four spatial directions means that a generic transformation is the product of a single boost in some direction and one *or two* rotations. For example, you could rotate in the $xy$ plane *and also* in the $zw$ plane.

Comment: Even with all known extra-dimensional theories already discovered, I could not find the associated (generalized) Lorentz transformation formula of those theories!